# Why did loss and acc fluctuated in spikes in training?

Tags: python, keras, lstm, loss

I train a LSTM network, it's not fluctuate all over, but spiking in several place. I've tried to adjust the learning rate. Is there any other method to solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

```html
model.add(LSTM(64, batch_input_shape=(len(TimeStep.fodder), TimeStep.TIME_STEP + 1, 10), return_sequences=True, activation='relu'))
model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=[categorical_accuracy])
history = model.fit(TimeStep.fodder, TimeStep.target, epochs=500, batch_size=len(TimeStep.fodder))
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the `batch_size` and weight clipping? Is your data shuffled? Are there any class imbalances? Is the data normalised?

Comment: I've tried batch_size and using sample_weight. Data is not shuffled. There is some class imbalance that I tried to overcome using sample_weight. The data is not normalised. @Vitrioil

Comment: Normalising the data might make the training more stable.